# Make border for title of section and subsection

Tags: sectioning, boxes

Hello how can i make border to the title of section and subsection.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
%% Je veux utiliser néanmoins des fontes qui « paraissent bien » en PDF
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

%% J'aime bien pouvoir contrôler mes hauts de page !
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Je veux pouvoir inclure des figures...
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%% ... des figures ``jpeg'' ou ``pdf'' ou "png"
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.png}

%% Je veux créer des Hyperdocuments
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

%% Je contrôle la taille de ma zone imprimée...
\usepackage{anysize}
%% ...en définissants les marges {gauche}{droite}{haute}{basse}
\marginsize{22mm}{14mm}{12mm}{25mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{28.44942pt}

%% J'inclue une bibliographie ; j'ai donc besoin du package natbib
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{bleuy}{rgb}{0.4,0.6,0.8}
\definecolor{blue(pigment)}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}
\definecolor{royalblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.14, 0.4}
\definecolor{oxfordblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.13, 0.28}
\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}
\definecolor{spirodiscoball}{rgb}{0.06, 0.75, 0.99}


\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % to insert PostScript figures  
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % new
\usepackage{booktabs,       % new
            makecell,       % new
            tabularx}       % new
 \usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}


 \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % redefined

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}


%%%%%%%%%table size

%%%%%%

\lfoot{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{IBM}}
\rfoot{\textcolor{bleuy}{\textbf{\small Année Universitaire 2017/2018}}}

\begin{document}

%% Voilà des hauts de page comme je les aime :
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection. #1}}
\lhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}}
\rhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}


%% Voilà mes légendes de figures comme je les aime :
\makeatletter
\def\figurename{{\protect\sc \protect\small\bfseries Fig.}}
\def\f@ffrench{\protect\figurename\space{\protect\small\bf \thefigure}\space}
\let\fnum@figure\f@ffrench%
\let\captionORI\caption
\def\caption#1{\captionORI{\rm\small #1}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%




%%%%%%%%Page garde
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\Large
\begin{center}






\end{center}
\vskip1cm


\begin{center}

\end{center}

 \begin{flushleft}

 \end{flushleft}

 \begin{flushleft}

 \end{flushleft}



\clearpage






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table des matières :
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.30}\small \normalsize

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures 

\listoftables

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.18}\small \normalsize

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Introduction :
\chapter*{Introduction}


Bla

bla

bla

bla
\vskip3mm

blabla et rebla !
\vskip3mm

Et merci à Ludovic BUHLER pour son aide !..


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chap 1 :
\chapter{Contexte général du projet}
bababab
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Présentation de l'organisme d'accueil}
\subsection{Présentation général }
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should make this a minimal example

Comment: Remove `aeguill` as soon as possible. And also the `pdftex` option from `graphicx` and `hyperref`.

Comment: oki and what is the solution of my probléme i want a make a border for every title of section

Comment: It's not work .